# Your payments are setup as X

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions

I understand *as* to be a conjunction and that a clause must follow. However, I've read some financial document which, in the context of how much I must pay the bank via a direct debit, said the following: "Your payments are setup as $100 per month."

Is this the same as "Your payments are setup for $100 per month", i.e., where both *for* and *as* are interchangeable prepositions?

Comment: No, your *for* is much better than the original *as*, and also better than the first alternative which occurred to me: *setup to be...*. The *as* is infelicitous. Either it's idiomatic in some English dialect I'm unfamiliar with, or it was written by a careless or non-native speaker.

Comment: *for* doesn't work, *as* it would be.  -- have you checked a good dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

In the IT industry, the phrase *X is set up as Y* carries the idea of configuring X to function as Y (see this [link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/168271/what-is-the-effect-of-the-choice-to-set-up-as-new-ipad) to an example). In the context of automated payments, then, the sentence "Your payments are setup as $100 per month." means that on the system, the payment function has been configured to pay (or transfer, etc) $100 per month. The single word *setup* is [popularly used in IT to mean *configure*](http://www.future-perfect.co.uk/grammar-tip/is-it-setup-set-up-or-set-up/). Using *setup* instead of the two words *set up* reinforces this line of reasoning.

The sentence "Your payments are setup for $100 per month" is ambiguous - it *can* mean the same as the *setup as* example, but it can also mean that you are charged $100 per month to arrange your payments, where the amounts of the payments are not specified. Here, [*for*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/for) can mean *purpose* (definition 4 in the link), leading to the former; or it can be read as *for the price of* (definition 8 in the link), giving rise to the latter.

So the **answer** to your question *Is this the same ...* is that there is considerable overlap between the two, but the *setup as* version is more specific. You can also say, "Your account has been set up to pay $100 per month [to a named person or account]."